# On learning the bayesian approach to portfolio optimization

Tags: portfolio-management, modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio-optimization

I am required by my course to write a small paper on the Bayesian approach to portfolio optimization, I am following *Applied statistical decision theory* [by] Raiffa, Howard. Which can be consulted online [here](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015022416351;view=1up;seq=256).

I begun following this text because I tried to read the paper by Zellner, Arnold, and V. Karuppan Chetty, 1965, *Prediction and decision problems in regression models from the Bayesian point of view*, and realized I was not following most of the math present in the paper.

My questions are: What is the recommended literature for understanding the Bayesian approach to portfolio management? any suggestions on the approach to the subject?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An introductory presentation by Michael Brandt from a seminar of Inquire Europe is [Bayesian Portfolio Construction](http://www.inquire-europe.org/seminars/2012/papers%20Budapest/Bayesian%20Portfolio%20Construction.pdf). His review [Portfolio Choice Problems](https://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/~mbrandt/papers/published/portreview.pdf) has a section on decision theory which could also be useful to you.

Another good choice is Attilio Meucci's *Risk and Asset Allocation* book which contains a whole chapter (ch 9) on Bayesian techniques in asset allocation. You might also want to look at his paper [The Black Litterman Approach: Original Model and Extensions](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1117574), which reviews Black Litterman, the most widely used Bayesian approach in asset allocation.

Answer (score 3):

As you are especially interested in applications in Finance I'll recommend [this book](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471920835.html) of Rachev which focus on Bayesian Methods in Finance